# Gradle build incorrectly fails because "@Override method does not override method from superclass"

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Code is below. The IDE is fine with the code, but gradle refuses to build saying:

> TextAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBindViewHolder(TextAdapter.SimpleTextHolder,int) in Adapter
>   public class TextAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
>
> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

I know it's wrong because I generated the method with Android Studio so I'm thinking it must be a gradle error?

RecyclerView adapter code:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ...R;
import ...jsonObjects.Nameable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextAdapter<T extends Nameable> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextAdapter.SimpleTextHolder> {

    private ArrayList<T> items;
    private ClickListener<T> clickListener;

    public TextAdapter(ArrayList<T> items, ClickListener<T> onClick) {
        this.items = items;
        this.clickListener = onClick;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleTextHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.holder_text, parent, false);
        return new SimpleTextHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleTextHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getName());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class SimpleTextHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView itemTitle;

        SimpleTextHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> clickListener.onClick(items.get(getAdapterPosition())));
        }

    }

    public interface ClickListener<T> {

        void onClick(T item);

    }

}
```

Comment: **If** at all, it is a bug in AS that it does not display the error, Gradle uses the normal Java compiler and it is very unlikely that it does it wrongly. ;-)

Comment: There error text was misleading but ultimately, yes, it was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by making your `SimpleTextHolder` class `static`, i.e.

```
static class SimpleTextHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Thanks!